# MVC CORE web application Angularjs http$ not returning data to api call

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

In my controller i have the following

```
 [HttpPost]
    public string AddEmployee(Employee Emp)
    {
        if (Emp != null)
        {
            _context.Employees.Add(Emp);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return "Employee Updated";
        }
        else
        {
            return "Invalid Employee";
        }
    }
```

When i use the following in my angularjs factory no data is passed.

```
EmployeeService.AddEmp = function (employee) {
            console.log(employee);
            var response = $http({
                method: "post",
                url: "/Home/AddEmployee",
                 data: JSON.stringify(employee),
                dataType: "json"
            });
            return response;
        }
```

but when i use the following data is passed. What am i doing wrong with the above code.

```
EmployeeService.AddEmp = function (employee) {
            console.log(employee);
            var response = $http({
                method: "post",
                url: "/Home/AddEmployee",
                params: {
                    employeeCode: JSON.stringify(employee.employeeCode),
                    firstName: JSON.stringify(employee.firstName),
                   lastName: JSON.stringify(employee.lastName),
                }
            });
            return response;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to add something like this:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
```

to WebApiConfig.Register